# What do you call the facial expression or the state just before bursting into tears?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, image-identification

What do you call this facial expression that forms just before bursting into tears? (Especially when a baby has been treated in a way he/she didn't expect and consider it unfair or feels neglected.
Of course this pitiful and sad expression with lower lip protrusion is most commonly seen in younger kids; and is not acceptable for adults or they will be considered to react childish.)

Actually I need to know the answer to complete these sentences :

"When the father yelled angrily at the baby, he (the baby) ..(?) and then burst into tears. "

"When the mom took the toy from the baby, he ...(?) and cried."

[image]

[image]

PS:
We have a phrasal verb in Farsi for describing this state and we use it for kids or adults, but when we hear it about a kid we would definitely think of a baby with this facial expression specially with the protruded lower lip. For adults, we would think of them in the state just before bursting into tears, for example; some winners react like this when they recieve their awards or when they are about to make a speech.

Note: Since I need to complete those sentences and they are about kids, if I know the term used for talking about/ referring to this kids' facial expression or state, that would solve my problem.

[image]

Comment: please clarify whether you want 'sulkiness' or 'hopeless sadness'.

Comment: That top kid looks way past pouting. Kid looks forlorn.

Comment: I want " sulkiness", @Dan.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I just wanted to show this type of  lips expression so I used this picture, too,@DCShannon. Thanks to you, I learned "forlorn". :)

Comment: Actually I am looking for a verb/ idiom/ expression for describing the stage just before bursting into tears, when our lips get this shape.  @Fard

Comment: I edited my post, @Fard.

Comment: They haven’t yet perfected it well enough to avoid the appearance of pouting (or to successfully avoid the tears), but I’d bet the upper teeth of both of these sad children are pressed hard against the inside of their lower lips and therefore they both have that “biting their lip to keep from crying-”/(lip-biting-) look to me.

Comment: It turned out that my answer (a lump in the throat) wasn't to the point, so I deleted it, and my comment up here too. But I left my criticism under Josh's answer. And tell you one thing: there may not be an exact term for this state in English (as suggested in [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/300994/142388) and [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/300880/142388)), but we will wait hopefully.  :)

Comment: Thank you so much, @Fard. But  "lump in the throat" is a useful  idiom and I'm happy to learn it. Regarding the answers, it seems that there is not an exact term for this state ( since we Iranians have a fixed expression for this facial/ lip expression I thought there might be an English equivalent too ). The good point is that all these answers are so helpful for English learners like me for sure. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you say what the expression in Farsi is? Did you try looking at an online/offline translator?

Comment: @Soudabeh - If I am sulky the next step (after pouting) is usually  (frustrated) anger.  Your photos do not suggest this.  The next step in both cases looks, to me, to be tears...

Comment: @Mari-LouA, We use this verb for describing this state or action: "boghz kardan, بغض کردن". Of course, I only ask my questions here after becoming totally disappointed in finding their answers on my own. :)  The translations which are shown in those translators are: "cry out", "hatred" ,grudge, spite, choking with tear, overflow with feelings, animus.

Comment: Yes, @Dan. But I have mentioned that point in my question too  "... forms just before we burst into tears?" : )

Comment: @Soudabeh - in which case I wonder whether you mean 'sulky' (*silently and obstinately ill-humoured*, OED).  Neither of your photos look remotely as though they have fight or resistance in them.

Comment: http://www.pardad.ir/uploadFiles/boghziiii.jpg and http://basijnews.ir/files/fa/news/1394/4/2/86985_612.jpg both taken from [Google images](https://www.google.it/search?q=%D8%A8%D8%BA%D8%B6+%DA%A9%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%86&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-6aqErrjKAhXDFywKHbOHCjQQsAQIIg#imgrc=QWmbtXCXKheBXM%3A)

Comment: Ok, @Dan. I'll edit my question. Thanks for your remark. ( I had this in my mind: the baby pouted and then sulked, of course when I was writing my question I still didn't know " pout" but I had the picture of a baby with a sad expression and protruded lower lip  just before sulking).

Comment: Yes, exactly  @ Mari-Lou A.:)  But sometimes we can swallow (?) back our tears while still keeping this facial/ lip expression for few more seconds, What  is the verb/ action that causes this facial expression form? When we say "بغض  كردن" we will automatically think of a person who is : feeling a lump in the throat+ pouting+  eyes filling with tear+ with sad look, but the most prominent part which comes to our mind is a person with "protrusion of his /her lower lip " بغض كردن".  I wish I could explain what I meant to say.

Comment: Babies do pout before they start to cry, but I personally don't pout at this stage (anymore!). I [purse my lips and clench my jaw](https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/a-few-subtle-ways-to-tell-if-someone-is-lying-to-you-25-photos-24.gif?w=455&h=320) (as if to hold back), flush and blush, [well up a bit](http://www.flickfilosopher.com/wptest/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/dwdoctorcries.gif), and then maybe start the waterworks, or maybe swallow the whole damn thing (ie, the lump).

Comment: ... So I'd say some of the other hits of your picture search are also relevant, @Mari-LouA, like [this one](http://khomari.com/wp-content/uploads/%D8%B9%DA%A9%D8%B3-%DA%AF%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%87-%DA%A9%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%86-11.jpg) .

Comment: Yes, @Fard. You're right. When we get older it is uncommon to pout in this situations. since this facial expression is a childish reaction, I edited my question. :)  http://www.livestrong.com/article/87337-children-pout/

Comment: Ricky Gervais who—like marmite, you either love or hate—is certainly puckering up in that last image. :) Moreover he didn't burst out crying, he [fought back the tears](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/251642/44619), some would say he [choked down his tears](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/277422/44619). Now, I'd be careful expanding this question to include adults who don't purse/pucker/pout/quiver their lips, because you're never going to have a single word or even idiom that covers the small children images and the last one you added.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for your helpful comments, @Mari-LouA. Happy to learn " pucker up" and " fight back the tears", " chok down one's tears". :)

Comment: Similar to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251593/a-word-for-when-you-are-almost-crying-but-not-quite-yet

Comment: English does not have a dedicated word for this state. (Some words or combinations of words can be used to describe aspects of this state, such as pout, quiver, or crumple, but they are not dedicated to this state specifically.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, @lunchmeat317. But I should translate those two sentences from Farsi into English, so I had to choose an answer with closest meaning to what I had in my mind.

Comment: @Soudabeh Of course. I understand completely.

Comment: "Sulking" connotes anger or frustration, rather than the abject sadness of bursting into tears.

Comment: I would say that Ricky Gervais is getting choked up, rather than puckering up.  In American English, "puckering up" - referring specifically to the lips - is more commonly used to refer to the act of preparing to kiss someone, or the facial expression that follows biting into a slice of lemon.  I've never heard it used to describe someone's face just before crying.

Comment: Also, be careful about the context in which you use the phrase "puckering up".  It is very often used as a crass way to describe a feeling of intense danger or fear, such as one might feel before skydiving, or while driving on a narrow switchback in South America.  In this usage, "puckering up" refers to the action of one's sphincter.

Comment: Yes, I noticed my mistake and already edited my post. Thanks for your remark, @Dr.Funk.

Comment: I see. @Dr.Frank, thanks again. I just found " to choke up"/ " to get choked up" too. Do you think I can use them for completing my sentences ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Quiver**: tremble involuntary, the action the lower lip does when a person is about to burst into tears or sob loudly.

> - His lower lip began to **quiver**, his face contorted, and the tears began.
> - Tears welled from his eyes now, his lower lip **quivering**...
> - ... her lower lip **quivered**, her eyes were puffy and red. She was on the brink of crying again.

**Puckered**: to draw together, crease, fold, and wrinkled. How a person's face appears when they can't hold back their tears.

> - the child’s face **puckered**, ready to cry
> - Speaking to the infant in a pitiful, compassionate voice, he said, “Oh! is the baby hurt? Poor thing. What did you do? Does it hurt? Show it to Mama.” Sure enough, my happy little cousin **puckered up**, started crying and made his way to his mother for emotional support.
> - The child **puckered up** her mouth in an effort to stop the tears but it was useless. They flowed down her dirt streaked cheeks...

Oxford Dictionaries: [*pucker*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pucker), [*quiver*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quiver)

Clair Danes, alias  Carrie Mathison in the TV series *Homeland*,  mastering the lower-lip quiver

[image]

Comment: Google Books Results for: ["face puckered" cry tears](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22face+puckered%22+cry+tears&tbm=bks) and ["lower lip quivered" cry tears](https://www.google.co.uk/#tbm=bks&q=%22lower+lip+quivered%22+cry+tears)

Comment: Image results: ["professional lower lip quiver"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22professional+lower+lip+quiver%22&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD6N241rfKAhWHsYMKHVNgD5AQ_AUICCgC&biw=1024&bih=653).

Comment: Ah dammit, might as well play the *quivering lip* GIF card: [Clare Danes, "professional bottom lip trembler" from the TV series, *Homeland*](http://rebelmommybookblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/tumblr_mcztp5ylLb1rum5tfo4_500.gif)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - It's striking that ***none*** of the OED citations for pucker (verb) connect the meaning ***draw together or contract into wrinkles, bulges, or folds*** with crying or being upset. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/154103?rskey=1YkHPk&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Mind you, neither do the citations for crumple (verb) -***To become incurved or crushed together; to contract and shrivel up; to become creased or wrinkled by being crushed together*** - http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/45223?isAdvanced=false&result=3&rskey=mA15U6&

Comment: @Dan and your point being? The definitions are mine, but **I also posted the link** to the **Oxford Dictionaries** definitions for ***pucker*** and ***quiver*** which is more than what you  did in your answer. I had the quiver GIF "card" for over a day before I finally had the nerve to post it :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - No they don't, and I'm sorry if you think they do.  I like thinking about the suggestions that are made.  I think pucker is a good word, although in my mind it doesn't especially communicate the emotional collapse in the OP images and I was curious to see what the OED citations would say.  The fact is pertinent.  Your GIF is a masterful stroke (as indeed are your hyperlinks, that replace all the guff with simply the word itself) ;-)

Comment: @Dan still, strange that you waited to post two comments citing the OED *after* the OP awarded this answer, insinuating that *pucker* is not associated with crying whereas in the OD link, the line: *the child’s face puckered, ready to cry* is actually cited by them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I hadn't noticed that your answer had won the coveted green tick.  Although it can be fun, really my motivation here is not the points or the prizes - I enjoy language.  I am not insinuating that 'pucker' is not associated with crying, I am saying that my instincts and some of the reference data suggest that both pout and pucker are *insufficiently involuntary* to describe the images that the OP posted

Answer (score 54):

"When the mom took the toy from the baby, ..."

"When the father yelled angrily at the baby, ..."

***his*** (little) **face crumpled** and then he burst into inconsolable tears.

***Crumple*** - *to become incurved or crushed together; to contract and shrivel up; to become creased or wrinkled by being crushed together* (OED) - suggests the important (as I see it) *involuntary* aspect of the facial expressions in the images.

Comment: "*his little face crumpled*" Well that certainly captures the 'noooo don't cry :c' feeling you get when you see someone with that face.

Comment: I like this one because pout doesn't quite capture the "about to rain tears of joy" feeling.

Comment: Google books result for "face crumpled" cry tears https://www.google.co.uk/#tbm=bks&q=%22face+crumpled%22+cry+tears

Comment: [Her mouth puckered, and she started to cry.](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pucker), [His face puckered, and he was ready to cry](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pucker), and [Her ​mouth puckered and I ​thought she was going to ​cry.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pucker) All three examples are taken from three separate dictionary entries. Are you really sure that OED *never* mentions crying with "pucker". I don't have a subscription, so I cannot check.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I could copy the OED 'pucker' entry to you if you want (not quite sure where tho')

Comment: No, there's no room. What's the date for the entry? I know that the OED can take years before it updates their entries.

Comment: 2005   News & Observer (Raleigh, N. Carolina) (Nexis) 25 Oct. c1   Behind the bench, Carolina coach Peter Laviolette's face puckered, like he'd eaten a piece of sour candy.  1987   Woman's Own 25 Apr. 30/1   Her scarlet crêpe dress was puckered into creases, causing the short skirt to ride high on her slim, shapely thighs.
2006   Daily Post (Liverpool) (Nexis) 11 Mar. (Features section) 1   A crease puckered my wife's creamy-smooth brow.

Comment: I like crumple the most because not only does it externally relate to how the face looks but it also relates to what is happening internally as their spirit [or at least composure] is crushed by their hurt [or joy?], for at least a moment.

Comment: Is the order perhaps that facial muscles first quiver and pucker (both actions being under voluntary control (just)), and ***then*** they crumple (involuntarily) ?

Answer (score 43):

The term is to ***[pout](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pout):***

> - to ​push the ​lower ​lip ​forward to show you are ​annoyed, or to ​push both ​lips ​forward in a ​sexually ​attractive way:
>
>   - *Vanessa always pouts if she doesn't get what she ​wants.
>       Caroline pouts her ​lips when she's putting on ​lipstick.*

Comment: Thanks, and if I want to describe his lips, how should I say it, @Josh61?

Comment: "He pouted his lips and cried."

Comment: Hmm... d'you not think pouting has a stubborn dimension; a wish to assert. The pictures suggest that all resistance has been worn down - defeat and hopelessness.

Comment: Just checked the OED - *To thrust out or protrude the lips, esp. so as to express petulance or sulkiness, or in order to make oneself sexually attractive; to show displeasure; to sulk*.

Comment: Not sad enough. An appropriate answer to this question must not miss the fact that these children are about to burst into tears.

Comment: @Fard Within context, I think *pout* can certainly be sad enough. "The baby pouted then burst into tears"

Comment: @ghoppe The one and only meaning that 'pout' has, is neutral on sadness, sexiness, etc, and as you rightly said, it depends on the context what is going on with the person. In my mother tongue (and also in the OP's mother tongue, I guess (based on her name)) there's a word that directly addresses the phenomenon that occurs in the body and the face just before you come undone and explode into tears. I think that's what the OP is after.

Comment: @Soudabeh: 'Pouty'.

Comment: When I hear the word "pout", I think of the aloof or petulant expression that fashion models use. Pout describes the position of the lip but doesn't imply sadness or elicit sympathy or pathos the way a complete answer to this question would - if anything, it implies stubbornness (which is what a pout looks like when the person *isn't* also welling up)

Answer (score 28):

Welling up.

"When the father yelled angrily at the baby ,he welled up and then burst into tears. "

"When the mom took the toy from the baby, he welled up and cried."

Comment: This is the only answer that's correct, rather than merely helpful.

Comment: "Welling up" refers to tears beginning to form in one's eyes, as if drawn up from a well, rather than the appearance of one's face prior to crying.

Answer (score 20):

The expression is called a *[pout](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pout)*:

> Push one’s lips or one’s bottom lip forward as an expression of petulant annoyance or in order to make oneself look sexually attractive.

In the case of children, it's the former definition, of course.

Pout (as a noun meaning a facial expression) appears to be not as old as the verb form. The first recorded use (from Chambers) is ca. 1591 in Nash's *[Astrologicall Prognostication](https://books.google.ca/books?id=xhY-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA329&lpg=PA329&dq=nash%20%22Plentie%20of%20poutes%22&source=bl&ots=wSi3CWUdXj&sig=bOJJrHcZh-9IcQQKh_9XD4PRCio&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY6pTo58DKAhUU3mMKHQ6tCTkQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=nash%20%22Plentie%20of%20poutes%22&f=false)*:

[image]

As a verb, it was known as early as 1300. One of the most familiar fairly early appearances (1592) is in Shakespeare's *Romeo and Juliet*:

> But, like a misbehaved and sullen wench,
>   Thou pout’st upon thy fortune and thy love.

Answer (score 12):

Each of these pictured children has a **petted lip** (noun).

The term is very well understood in Ireland/Scotland, but I'm not sure about elsewhere!

Quoting [Dictionary of the Scots Language](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/sndns2877)

> **petted lip**:  The sign of a spoilt or sulky child, that is, the lower lip
>   protruding in front of the upper lip:
>
> *Never mind the petted lip. You're not going and that's that.*

Also from Oxford English Dictionary:

> **petted** - Offended or sulky at feeling slighted or ill-used; piqued;
>   pettish. Now chiefly in petted lip n. the protrusion of the lower lip
>   in front of the upper, a pout.

As a verb, one could say :

"*When the father yelled angrily at the baby, he **petted his lip** and then burst into tears.* ".

Comment: Hm. Semantically related to "petulant", I'm guessing.

Comment: @keshlam: actually, I'm wondering if it's just a different pronunciation of *pout*. (For the record, I've never heard of "petted lip".)

Comment: Google for "petted lip" images and compare to 'pouted lip' images; the results are significantly different.

Answer (score 11):

> Grimace
>   :  a facial expression usually of disgust, disapproval, or pain - [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grimace)

With reference to your sample sentences:

"When the father yelled angrily at the baby, he (the baby) grimaced and then burst into tears. "

"When the mom took the toy from the baby, he grimaced and cried."

Comment: I don't think grimaced is appropriate in either of these examples.

Comment: @5arx What would you call it?

Comment: I'm still thinking about it, but I definitely think grimace is a bad fit here.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest "cloud up":

> **cloud up**: 1. Lit. [for the sky] to get cloudy, as if it were going to rain. 
>   2. Fig. [for someone] to grow very sad, as if to cry.
>
> <sup>Source: [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cloud+up)</sup>

"When the father yelled angrily at the baby, he clouded up and then burst into tears."

Comment: Nice suggestion, mtebob. I added a bit of formatting to your answer, and included the relevant definitions from your linked source, to make the answer more self-contained, but I think this is a good answer. +1

Comment: +1. Good one. But having a clouded-up face doesn't mean that you're struggling with upcoming tears, and that's the point, kinda. For example, [**this**](http://howtoreadfaces.com/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/sad-baby-580091_960x480.jpg) can be called a clouded-up face too.

Answer (score 4):

These expressions, per se, don't have a common English name, like grin does. "Petted lip" is probably correct, but I'd never heard it before, and I used to teach animation. "Grimace" is correct, physiologically, but would connote anger or disgust to most readers. "Pout" is a lip motion, and the brows are doing a lot of work in those expressions.

One often sees something like "the child's face fell," even though it's the body language that falls (shoulders sagging, head bowing, spine curving) more than face parts. Also, faces "crumple", certainly that baby's face is crumpled.

Also, someone please add a HAPPY baby: faces that sad hurt the feelings of even casual viewers! :)

Answer (score 4):

The *state* just before bursting into tears is sometimes called *on the verge of tears*.

See for example, this dictionary.cambridge.com page for [on the verge of](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-the-verge-of) ("*If you are on the verge of something [...], you are very ​close to ​experiencing it*") and the second item under [**verge¹**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/verge) at freedictionary.com ("*The point beyond which an action, state, or condition is likely to begin or occur*"), which gives *on the verge of tears* as an example.

Answer (score 3):

The most common way I have heard this expressed is "they looked like they were about to cry." Sometimes, it will be said that a person's lower lip started to quiver. I'll be interested to see if someone comes up with a really good answer, because I really think this is a bit of a gap in the English lexicon.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why *frown* hasn't been mentioned yet:

> Furrow one’s brow in an expression of disapproval, displeasure, or concentration ([OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/frown))

True, the dictionary definition makes no mention of the mouth. However, when frowning due to being sad or upset, as the question describes, it's generally understood that the mouth also takes a particular shape, including pouting lips and downward-turned corners.

In fact, if you ask someone to draw a frowning face, they're likely to draw an "inverse smiley face" without any eyebrows at all. For example, the ubiquitous emoticon `:(` is commonly referred to as the "frowny face" or "frown".

Comment: As far as I can tell, calling this a 'frown' is unique to America.  In Britain and Australia, a frown would be understood to be something closer to a scowl.

Comment: @EasyTiger Thanks for the insight, I had no idea. So frowning isn't associated with sadness in those countries? Or does a scowl apply to more than just anger or frustration?

Comment: The OED definition you provided pretty much covers it.  It's about the forehead area rather than the mouth.  

Think  >:|  rather than  :(

Comment: Makes sense. I wonder if the phrase "turn that frown upside down" has American origins, then.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone older than a baby:

> Verklempt: overcome with emotion; clenched

Yiddish origin

Comment: Please add a citation.  This may be exactly right, but without being able to look at a citation, all the Yiddish-naïve users will be perplexed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the phrase "lost his composure" well represents that pre-tears emotional state the OP wishes to express in the example sentences.  That face in the example images is most commonly seen in children because adults have generally mastered the art of maintaining their composure around other people.  If you really need a single word, the word that comes to mind is crestfallen.
([disappointed and ​sad because of having ​failed ​unexpectedly](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/crestfallen))  But "When mom took the toy away, he became crestfallen and cried" sounds more like a writer trying to force a square word into a round sentence to me than something like  "...his countenance morphed rapidly toward sadness as he lost a brief tussle with his composure and burst into tears"

Answer (score 2):

Consider, ***crease***

> Cause a crease to appear temporarily in (the face or its features), typically as a result of the expression of an emotion or feeling. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/pt/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o/ingl%C3%AAs-americano/crease)
>
> *His [little] [face creased](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=face+creased&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cface%20creased%3B%2Cc0) and tears welled in his eyes*

Answer (score 2):

One might say, after having his candy taken away, that "*the child's face **contorted** as he tried to hold back tears*".

The word ***pout*** is not really appropriate.  In American English, pouting is melodramatic or insincere.  A child might pout (stick out their lip, whine, etc., but without tears) after being told "no" to more ice cream as a way to get their parents to give in and say "yes".  This is not the same as a child who is about to cry because they skinned their knee, for example.

Answer (score 1):

While you are looking for a verb, the noun grief and its many synonyms define this expression and feeling very well.

**grief**

> noun: deep sorrow, especially that caused by
>   someone's death. *"she was overcome with grief"*

**synonyms:**

> sorrow,
>   misery, sadness, anguish, pain, distress, heartache, heartbreak,
>   agony, torment, affliction, suffering, woe, desolation, dejection,
>   despair;

Answer (score 1):

I think 'stricken' can apply but only to the stage before tears of unhappiness or grief. Clare Danes in that gif certainly looks stricken.

Quoting [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stricken)

> **stricken**
>
> seriously affected by an undesirable condition or unpleasant feeling.
>
> *"Raymond was stricken with grief"*
>
> (Of a person’s face or look) showing great distress:
>
> *"she looked at Anne's stricken face, contorted with worry"*

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer to your question (few of the answers here are) but the truth is that a very good word for what you want to express is **consternation**.

> Full Definition of consternation :  amazement or dismay that hinders
>   or throws into confusion

--Webster's

> noun
>   1. a sudden, alarming amazement or dread that results in utter confusion; dismay.

--Dictionary.com

Answer (score 1):

*Quiver* is the answer to your question.

Or in a more casual term ***sour lips*** is what most of my friends call their babies in the moment just before they burst to cry.

"Oh no, she is doing **sour lips**...."

Answer (score 1):

**scrunched up face**

**scrunch** (v.)

> (transitive) To crumple and squeeze to make more compact.
>
> (with object "one's face") To contract the muscles of one's face so as
> to draw their facial features together, out of pain, discomfort,
> uncertainty, etc.  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrunch#English)

---

> But she'd taken one look at my **scrunched up face** and all she'd
> said was, “Please don't cry!” [Martin Guinness; *Melting*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Melting/vQWHDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22scrunched%20up%20face%22%20cry&pg=PT30&printsec=frontcover)

> Kevin turned to her with a **scrunched up face** and tear filled eyes.
> [Jeffrey Matthews; *Carry Us All*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Carry_Us_All/_TeoDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22scrunched%20up%20face%22%20tear&pg=PT218&printsec=frontcover)

> "That's not fair!" he yelled, but his **scrunched up face** told me he
> was fighting back tears. [Susan Calhoun; *Freeway Close*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Freeway_Close/-kXQY5fHgGwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22scrunched%20up%20face%22%20tear&pg=PA243&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

The word used by my GM as an adjective was "schipsche."  Whenever a baby would begin to wrinkle its face and its lower lip would begin to tremble & protrude before crying she'd say "Awe, look at him with the schipsche (pron, ship shuh) lip.  I do not know whether this was German, Yiddish, Hebrew, or some other language's slang and I never asked her the origin of it and have never been able to find it in English, German, Yiddish or Hebrew dictionaries.  It could just have been one of those "family" words because no middle-easterner, European, Israeli or German has ever heard of it.

Answer (score -2):

I have a possible neologism for this common and sorry state:

*liquiver*...

conjoining the sense of welling-up or becoming wet or liquid
AND
that quivery thing we do when we try to fight it.

Or I guess one could say:

*puckquify*

:@)